# MHW How to enable damage meter in training area?

Tags: monster-hunter-world, monster-hunter-world-iceborne

As can be seen in this [video](https://youtu.be/6mmAXxJF0l0?t=117)(actual timestamp), it can be seen, that its possible to track hits and damage in the training area. For me, this is not turned on and I couldn't find the option to enable it.

**Is it paid content or how do I enable the damage meter?**

---

To clarify beforehand, I am talking about the **PS4** version and not some PC mod.

[image]

I do see the damage number of each hit (34 in the picture), but I don't see the total damage (238) or number of hits (7).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Option screen, with button guide]

Surprisingly, the **Button Guide option** of your **HUD Display** is apparently tied with the damage log. I presume this is because all of the training area UI is tied with this button guide, not a good UX design but understandable.

If you still do not see the damage log, make sure you are hitting the pole for the base game training area, and the wagon for the Iceborne training area. Damage log is counted only for them.

- **With Button Guide**:
  [image: Damage log displayed with Button Guide on]
- **Without Button Guide**:
  [image: Damage log not displayed without Button Guide]

Comment: Ugh, good to know. The button guide is 1 of the 2 things I have disabled there. Will try later!